# Custom Field Not Visible on Page Layout in Production Org

Tags: custom-field, page-layout, sandbox, standard-objects

I am having what seems to be a weird issue. I added a custom field titled "Status" to the Account object. I then went into the page layout and added this field while also marking it required. Although, once I go to add a new account it does not show in the page.

What is confusing me is when I follow the same process as my Production Organization it shows with no issues. I have also done an Inbound change set from my sandbox to production organization. Users are the same in both orgs as well as permissions, yet I cannot replicate the issue within my Sandbox.

The only users we have are system admins at the moment, which all have the permissions to view, edit, delete, etc.

I am stumped, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution! I went into my permission sets and noticed my Sales User did not have the correct object settings permissions. I was able to give my custom field the appropriate read/write capabilities and now it is working as intended!

Answer (score 0):

If you've converted your lightning record page to a dynamic form, the classic page layout no longer controls the layout you see in Lightning. You’ll need to update/add the field in the lightning app builder. The easiest way to get there is to click Edit Page from the gear menu when looking at a record detail page.